# How to deploy case-insensitive embedded firebird database?

Tags: c#, firebird, case-sensitive

I'm trying to find out how to create **CI** firebird embedded database. I've found ([here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-collations.html#langrefupd21-collations-unicode)) that there are some character sets each of them has one or many collations. So, UTF8 has UCS_BASIC, UNICODE and UNICODE_CI collations. From documentation I can set any collation for any column during table creation. My question is: Is it possible to set collation on whole database? Or I have to impose collation on all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-database.html)

> CREATE {DATABASE | SCHEMA}    ...    [PAGE_SIZE [=] size]    ...
>   [DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset [COLLATION collation]]    ...
>   [DIFFERENCE FILE 'filepath']
>
> size  ::=  4096 | 8192 | 16384

Also check out [this](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/charsets.htm) page and this [link](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/caseinsensitivesearch.htm) from it specifically
about case insensitive searches and collations on columns.

The good news is that you can set it both by database **and** column.

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840872/firebird-configuration-turn-case-sensitivity-off) out - you can also use "shadow" columns if you
can't get exactly what you want "out of the box" - i.e. UPPER()
function.